# what does "_height" mean in css?

Tags: html, height, css

I'm familiar with

```
height
```

and

```
min-height
```

but in the code I am looking at there is `_height: 100px`
What's that about?  Is it an IE thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a [CSS hack](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#unrecommended-vendor_prefix).

IE6 will ignore the underscore and read it as `height`; real browsers will (correctly) ignore the whole line.

Comment: ah ok.  Do they not recognize 'height' by itself ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Yes, it does.  The point is to set a separate `height` for IE6 only.

Comment: So a selector with both `height` and `_height` set to the same `90px` value would be pointless, right? There's no reason that explains what I'm reading in one of our CSS files?

Comment: No or people would just use height.  the reason is that ie6 recognizes height BUT USES IT AS MINIMUM HEIGHT.  so it looks really different.  To get around this you use both height (ok in most browers) and then another value with miminum_height to actually set the height using a different value.  Or something like that ;)